# How to keep the blue background color after right clicking the selected text in QLabel to generate a QMenu?

Tags: pyside2, qlabel, qmenu

I want to keep the selected text keep the blue background color,but when i right clicked the text to generate a menu,the selected text will turn gray.how should i do.
when i clicked the qlabel text to make it selected,the result is like this picture.
And when i right click the selected text,the blue color turn gray.
here is my demo code.

[image]

[image]

```
import pyperclip
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import  Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QCursor
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QLabel,QMenu,QAction,QHBoxLayout,QApplication,QWidget

class moreInfoLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.rightMenuShow)#开放右键策略
        self.setStyleSheet('''
        QMenu {
            border: Opx;
            font-size: 9pt;
            width:100px;
            background-color:white
        }

        QMenu::item { 
            width:160px;
            font-family: "Microsoft YaHei";
            border: 0px;
            min-height: 15px;
            max-height: 26px;
            padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
            font-size: 9pt; 
        }
        
        QMenu::item:selected { 
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
        }
        QLabel{
            font-size:13px;
            font-family:微软雅黑;

        }
        ''')

    def rightMenuShow(self, pos):
        print(self)
        menu = QMenu(self)
        menu.addAction(QAction('复制', menu))
        menu.addAction(QAction('全选', menu))

        menu.triggered.connect(self.menuSlot)
        menu.exec_(QCursor.pos())
        self.setStyleSheet('''
        QMenu {
            border: Opx;
            font-size: 9pt;
            width:100px;
            background-color:white
        }

        QMenu::item { 
            width:160px;
            font-family: "Microsoft YaHei";
            border: 0px;
            min-height: 15px;
            max-height: 26px;
            padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
            font-size: 9pt; 
        }
        
        QMenu::item:selected { 
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
        }
        QLabel{
            font-size:13px;
            font-family:微软雅黑;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
        }
        ''')
    
    def menuSlot(self, act):
        if act.text() == '复制':
            pyperclip.copy(self.selectedText())
        elif act.text() == '全选':
            len1 = len(self.text())
            self.setSelection(0,len1)
            self.selectedText = self.text

class Demo(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()

        self.moreinfo = moreInfoLabel("YOUJIAN")
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.moreinfo)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is there any way to solve this problem

Comment: Are you asking that the text remain highlighted and selected while the context menu is showing?  Or do you just want to change the color of text?

Comment: Yes,I want to keep the text remain highlighted and selected while the context menu is showing.

Comment: You could use a qlineedit with some custom styling to make it look like a qlabel

Comment: @yongnisang Why are you creating a custom menu for options that the default behavior already provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the menu is shown, the widget uses the `Inactive` [color group](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorGroup-enum) of the palette, which is the one normally used when the widget is in a window that is not active.

The simple solution is to temporarily replace the `Highlight` and `HighlightedText` [color role](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum) for that group and restore the original palette afterwards. This step is necessary for consistency, as the default `Inactive` colors should be kept in case the window is *actually* unfocused.

Note that in the following example I did some changes:

- the custom context menu signal is normally used when managing the menu from *another* object, like its parent, but when it's actions have results in the same class it's better to use the `contextMenuEvent()` handler;
- it's better to check the menu result against the triggered QAction, not its text;
- the pyperclip module is unnecessary as Qt already provides [QClipboard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html);
- do **not** overwrite `self.selectedText` with `self.text`, otherwise `self.selectedText()` will always return the *full* text of the label, even if there is no selection;

```py
class MoreInfoLabel(QLabel):
    _defaultPalette = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse|Qt.TextEditable)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
        QMenu {
            border: Opx;
            font-size: 9pt;
            width:100px;
            background-color:white
        }

        QMenu::item { 
            width:160px;
            font-family: "Microsoft YaHei";
            border: 0px;
            min-height: 15px;
            max-height: 26px;
            padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
            font-size: 9pt; 
        }
        
        QMenu::item:selected { 
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
        }
        QLabel{
            font-size:13px;
            font-family:微软雅黑;
        }
        ''')

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        oldPalette = self.palette()
        tempPalette = self.palette()
        tempPalette.setBrush(tempPalette.Inactive, tempPalette.Highlight, 
            oldPalette.highlight())
        tempPalette.setBrush(tempPalette.Inactive, tempPalette.HighlightedText, 
            oldPalette.highlightedText())
        self.setPalette(tempPalette)

        menu = QMenu(self)
        copyAction = menu.addAction('复制')
        selectAction = menu.addAction('全选')

        res = menu.exec_(event.globalPos())
        self.setPalette(oldPalette)

        if res == copyAction:
            QApplication.clipboard().setText(self.selectedText())
        elif res == selectAction:
            self.setSelection(0, len(self.text()))
```

That said, QLabel already provides the menu entries you're trying to replace. If you did that for localization purposes, then overriding the default menu behavior is just wrong, as the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure it is possible to achieve what you are asking, however I would suggest a simpler alternative.

Instead of using a `QLabel`,  It would be much simpler to achieve similar or identical behavior using a `QLineEdit`.  You can set the line edit to read only and `setFrame(False)` to make it appear identical to a QLabel, with the added bonus that maintaining the current selection when opening a context menu is the default behavior for a QLine edit.

For example:

In the image below, the one on the right is the QLineEdit...

```
import pyperclip
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import  Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QCursor
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QLabel,QMenu,QAction,QHBoxLayout,QApplication,QWidget, QLineEdit
QSS = ("""QMenu {
    border: Opx;
    font-size: 9pt;
    width:100px;
    background-color:white
}
QMenu::item:selected {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
QMenu::item {
    width:160px;
    font-family: "Microsoft YaHei";
    border: 0px;
    min-height: 15px;
    max-height: 26px;
    padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
QLabel{
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:微软雅黑;
    color: black;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}"""   # Added styles below to make it look identical to label
"""QLineEdit{
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:微软雅黑;
    color: black;
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
}""")

class Demo(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()
        self.moreinfo = QLabel("YOUJIAN")
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.moreinfo)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.moreinfo.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        ########################################
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit(self)            # <--- added these lines
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.lineedit.setText("YOUJAIN")
        self.lineedit.setFrame(False)
        self.lineedit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.setStyleSheet(QSS)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]